# Unable to perform actions on initialized states in qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I have the code below which initalized a state in a quantum circuit then tries to perform some simulation. This doesn't work if I keep the initialize line uncommented, but runs just fine if I comment it out. It seems to error out at the `get_unitary` line. How can I initialize a circuit and also perform a simulation on it?

Error message `qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'Data for experiment "circuit-X" could not be found.'`

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.initialize('01', circuit.qubits)
circuit.h(0)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.cx(1, 0)
circuit.save_unitary(label="unitary", pershot=False)
simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
result = simulator.run(circuit).result()
unitary = result.get_unitary(circuit)
print(unitary.round(3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** There are two issues with your code, the first one is that `initialize` introduces a `reset`. Consider using `prepare_state` (see [docs](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#prepare_state)) instead. The second one, is that you need to transpile the circuit before running it in a backend.

**Problem one**: `initialize`
The [`initialize` instruction](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#initialize) introduced a `reset` in the front, as part of the state preparation.

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuitrcuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.initialize('01', circuit.qubits)
circuit.decompose().draw('mpl')
```

[image: two resets, followed by State Preparation]

You can, instead, use [`prepare_state`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#prepare_state) directly:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuitrcuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.prepare_state('01', circuit.qubits)
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image: state preparation]

**Problem two**: transpilation
Not all backends support the instructions included in Qiskit, so you need to convert the circuit into one that the backend understands. This process is sometimes called *transpilation*.

Qiskit includes a transpiler that, given a circuit and a backend, converts that circuit into a new one that can run on that backend:
`circuit_transpiled = transpile(circuit, backend=simulator)`

**Conclusion**: your working example:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit_aer import Aer

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
# circuit.initialize('01', circuit.qubits)
circuit.prepare_state('01', circuit.qubits)

circuit.h(0)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.cx(0, 1)
circuit.cx(1, 0)
circuit.save_unitary()
simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')

circuit_transpiled = transpile(circuit, backend=simulator)
result = simulator.run(circuit_transpiled).result()

unitary = result.get_unitary(circuit_transpiled.name)
print(unitary.round(3))
```

```
[[ 0.5+0.j  0.5+0.j  0.5-0.j  0.5+0.j]
 [-0.5-0.j  0.5+0.j  0.5+0.j -0.5-0.j]
 [-0.5-0.j  0.5+0.j -0.5+0.j  0.5+0.j]
 [ 0.5+0.j  0.5+0.j -0.5+0.j -0.5+0.j]]
```

Comment: Adding prepare_state errors out in `result` with `qiskit_aer.aererror.AerError: 'unknown instruction: state_preparation'`. Nothing useful comes up when searching the error message.

Comment: @Hercislife related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34396/aererror-unknown-instruction-c-unitary-while-using-control-unitary-operator

Comment: I extended the answer with details and how to change the example to make it runnable.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!